# Want to convert pygame project to windows executable file

Tags: python, pygame

I created python game with pygame from book called 'Python crash course'. It has 9 .py file (1 to run game, other 8 for modules like: settings, game_functions, etc.) and one folder where are 2 image files. I want to share this project with my friends who don't have python and pygame, so I want to convert entire project to .exe (windows executable)

I have tried cx_Freeze, py2exe and pyinstaller. Pyinstaller was the most successful one, It created .exe file but however when I run it it's getting black screen and getting closed. I think the reason is that it can't reach modules (8 .py files) and/or image files that I'm using.

Here is main .py code, whats it importing and stuff..

```py
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Group
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf
from game_stats import GameStats
from scoreboard import Scoreboard
from button import Button


def run_game():
        pygame.init()
...
```

If you need any additional information feel free to ask!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me recommand you to use `Markdown` whenever you have code to show; it is really simple, and makes it really easier to read.
For example, add *```python* before your code and ``` at the end. Code will be formatted and will have syntax highlighting. For example, instead of being shown on one single line, your code becomes:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Group
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf
from game_stats import GameStats
from scoreboard import Scoreboard
from button import Button

def run_game(): pygame.init() ...
```

Now, onto your issue. According to the [cx_Freeze documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest):

> Different bases serve for different types of application on Windows (GUI, console application or service).

With cx_Freeze, you need to specify the application is a GUI (Graphical User Interface) in the `setup.py` file, like:

```py
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "guifoo",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My GUI application!",
        executables = [Executable("guifoo_main.py", base=base)])
```

I haven't checked all of the other "python to standalone app converters", but I guess there might be something similar that needs to be changed for the app to be executed correctly, and not as a console app. When this kind of issues happen, I suggest you to take the time to read it's documentation carefully.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response! It helped me a lot. Sorry for making this post uncomfortable to read, I'm new to stackoverflow and did not know Markdown function. The only thing I needed to add to your code is including image files since cx_Freeze could not reach these files by itself so included files with 

options={'build_exe': {'include_files': include_files}},